# Xamarin Android profiler memory dump?

Tags: android, xamarin, out-of-memory, heap-memory

For the few days, I've been trying to find out why my app allocates massive amounts of memory and crashes. I'll open a few layouts that admittedly is not optimized. But I cant figure out why sometimes StartActivity() will allocate up to 80MB at a time, and why that memory wont release when I close the activity.

I created a test application filled with images and two layouts that call each other. Using Xamarin Profiler, I came across this memory dump, and I cant figure out what is calling this and how can I have it called more often for my real app?

Please, any insights would be lovely. [image]

Answer (score 0):

> I cant figure out what is calling this and how can I have it called more often for my real app?

The [Memory Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler) in Android Studio can help you to see how your app allocates memory over over time. It could also be used for xamarin android app.

And try to use [`IComponentCallbacks2`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.IComponentCallbacks2/) interface and implement `Application.OnTrimMemory` to incrementally release memory based on current system constraints.

You could refer to [Manage your app's memory](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory) for more information.